# when clicking the zoom-in button or any button in the Webpage, it doesn't navigate to details page

Tags: html, asp.net, visual-studio-2019

> In visual studio2019, I built a project called OdeToFood using .net 2.1, and I'm having a problem when I click the zoom button on a webpage that doesn't navigate to the page I want (Detail page), and it stays the same page when I hit this zoom button, though than I have checked the code several times, except that I don't know where the problem is.

[here is the Detail code for the zoom button]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using OdeToFood.Core;
using OdeToFood.Data;

namespace OdeToFood.Pages.Restaurants
{
public class DetailModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly IRestaurantData restaurantData;

    [TempData]
    public string Message { get; set; }

    public Restaurant Restaurant { get; set; }

    public DetailModel(IRestaurantData restaurantData)
    {
        this.restaurantData = restaurantData;
    }

    public IActionResult OnGet(int restaurantId)
    {
        Restaurant = restaurantData.GetById(restaurantId);
        if (Restaurant == null)
        {
            return RedirectToPage("./NotFound");
        }
        return Page();
    }
} }
```

[here is the code for the model of Detail]

```
@page "{restaurantId:int}"

@model OdeToFood.Pages.Restaurants.DetailModel
@{
ViewData["Title"] = "Detail";
 }
<h2>@Model.Restaurant.Name</h2>
<div>
Id: @Model.Restaurant.Id
</div>
<div>
Location: @Model.Restaurant.Location
</div>
<div>
Cuisine: @Model.Restaurant.Cuisine
</div>
<a asp-page="./List" class="btn btn-default">All Restaurants</a>
```

[here is the code for zoom-in in the list of the restaurant]

```
@page 
@model OdeToFood.Pages.Restaurants.ListModel
@{
ViewData["Title"] = "Restaurants";
 }
<h1>Restaurants</h1>

<form method="get">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="search" class="form-control"
                   asp-for="SearchTerm" />
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button type="submit" value="" class="btn btn-default">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
                </button>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

<table class="table">    
        @foreach (var restaurant in Model.Restaurants)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@restaurant.Name</td>
                <td>@restaurant.Location</td>
                <td>@restaurant.Cuisine</td>
                <td>
                        <a class="btn btn-lg"
                           asp-page="./Detail"
                           asp-all-route-restaurantId="@restaurant.Id">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-zoom-in"></i>
                        </a>
                   
                    <a class="btn btn-lg"
                       asp-page="./Edit"
                       asp-all-route-restaurantId="@restaurant.Id">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i>
                    </a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
</table>
```

> Note: When I type the URL on the web page manually like https://localhost:44040/Restaurants/Detail/1, where I can see the detail page with the contents of the restaurant with Id=1, but when I click the zoom-in button it doesn't navigate to the page.

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `asp-all-route-restaurantId="@restaurant.Id"`

to `asp-route-restaurantId="@restaurant.Id"`

removing the `-all-` from the tag.